# Как вставить функцию в конструкцию echo <<<END END; ?

Tags: php

сабж.
есть кусок кода

> echo <<< END
>
> blah blah blah
>
> END;

(пробел перед END специально, ибо тут редактор как-то коряво обрабатывает без пробела).

как внутрь blah blah вставить функцию? переменные там вставляются, а функции как сделать?

Comment: `$foo = Bar();` и переменную в нужное место!

Comment: Так как внутри HEREDOC не могут быть изменены или созданы новые переменные, то все значения, которые Вы хотите вычислить внутри HEREDOC могут быть вычислены до него, а результаты вычислений использовать внутри.  
А вообще прямой ответ на вопрос: никак.  
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: @alexlz, только для `PHP >= 5.3.0`

Comment: @sergiks А причём тут анонимные функции? У функции id есть имя id. У переменной $expr есть имя $expr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php.net говорите... http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

```
 function id($args) {return $args;}
 $expr = id;
 $a = <<<EOF
 2 * 2 = {$expr(2 * 2) }
 Примерно.
 EOF;
 echo $a;
```

Comment: Занятно. Век живи, век учись.

Comment: очень интересно...спасибо :)

Comment: @Garfild Не мне. Автору -- mcamiano at ncsu dot edu (http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Может, в два хода?

```
$tmpl = <<<END
trololo
function output here: %s
int variable here: %d
Ho ho ho
END;
printf( $tmpl, str_repeat('-',30), pow(3,4));
```